# Insufficient Privileges error after adding a Flow (Visual Workflow)

Tags: visual-workflow, insufficient-privileges

I recently created a Flow (called from a page layout button) and my functional test of it worked when logged in as Admin. But I ran into the "Insufficient Privileges" error when testing it as a sales user. You know, this one:

> **Insufficient Privileges**
>
> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

All object and field permissions (the Flow performs DML) are the same between the two profiles for the relevant objects and fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a user to run a Flow, they must be explicitly given permissions to do so. There are 3 options for enabling users to run flows. From least to most permissive they are:

1. Check the "**Run Flows**" system permission option on a
   **profile/permission set**
2. Check the "**Flow User**" option on a
   **user** record
3. Check the "**Manage Flow**" system permission
   option on a **profile/permission set**

In my case, I elected to use permission sets (bundled with other permissions related to the same release) for their advantage with maintainability, adding the 1st option to the sales users' permission set and the 3rd option to the admins' permission set.